# How to embed Google Adwords Editor for Woocommere Based Website

Tags: wordpress, web, woocommerce, google-ads-api

What is the best way to integrate Google Adwords editor or a similar tool with woocommerce based website so that Google Ads can be created in the most efficient manner?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this plugin: http://www.woothemes.com/products/google-product-feed/

Alternately if you just wanted to use regular AdWords you could create a CSV file that matched the AdWords Editor file import spec. You’ll get this spec by exporting a campaign using AdWords Editor and looking at the file.

I’ve built several automated Google AdWords creation tools over the last couple of years using this approach. They’ve worked more or less like this:

1. Get a list of all the products from the store (using an API,
   database dump or CSV export).
2. Foreach product create an adgroup.
3. Foreach adgroup create one text advert with the landing page url set
   to the product url.
4. Foreach adgroup create an exact and phrase match keyword with the product name.
5. Export it as a CSV file.

That’ll give you the basic structure fairly quickly. After that you need to add extra keywords if needed and probably extra adgroups over time.

Getting the automated advert writing 90% right is fairly easy. It’s just about merging the product name into some text. Getting it 100% right is a far bigger problem. It’s far easier to have your code spit out an ad and then pass it onto someone for polishing up.

Comment: A nice, neat answer. Welcome to StackOverflow Peter.